# Is it possible to create a long running process in NodeJs

Tags: python, node.js, celery, background-process

Is it possible to create a long running process in NodeJs to handle many background operations without interrupting the main thread; something like Celery in Python.

Hint, it's highly preferable to be able to manage that long-running process, in case of failure, or need to be restarted, away from the main process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html is the right API to create long-running processes, you will have complete control over the child processes (access to stdin/out/err, can send signals etc). <strike>This approach however requires that your node process is parent of those children.</strike>. If you want the child to outlive the parent, take a look at `options.detached` during child creation (and following `child.unref()`).

Please note, however, that Node.js is suited extremely well to avoid such architecture. Typically node.js do all the background stuff in the main thread. I've been writing apps with lots of traffic (like thousands requests per second), with DB, Redis and RabbitMQ access all from the main thread and without any child processes - and it was worked fine, as it should, thanks to Node's evented IO system.

I'm generally using child_process api only to launch separate executables (e.g. ffmpeg to transcode some video file), apart of such scenarios separate processes are probably not what you want.

There is also cluster api which allow single master to handle numerous worker processes, though I think it isn't what you look for, either.

Comment: Great answer @Nopik. But my main concern here with child processes is that if the parent process dies, it will take down the child with it, I want to make sure this won't happen, is that possible? Also, can you provide a link for Node cluster api and a number of use cases. Appreciated!

Comment: I also edited my answer to supply info about child outliving the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can create child process to handle your background operations. And then use messages to pass data between the new process and your main thread.

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

**Update**

It looks like you need to use the server queues, sort of beanstalkd http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/ + https://www.npmjs.com/package/fivebeans.

Comment: Thanks a lot @stdob, I just updated my question, can you please have a look.

Comment: You can handle different types of events such as "error" or "exit": https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error Or send a "kill" signal, and after restart a child process from the main process: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal

Comment: Thanks for referring to Beanstalk

Comment: http://adam.herokuapp.com/past/2010/4/24/beanstalk_a_simple_and_fast_queueing_backend/

Comment: But I have some question stands: does the consumers and producers will be child processes or completely separate processes (shall I consider Node clustering?)